# r.html.render in requests-html can not work in python 3.8

Tags: python, python-requests-html

I want use requests-html and Beautifulsoup to get html, but the function of'response.html.render()'didn't work.

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession
session = HTMLSession()
response = session.get('https://www.xxxxxxx')
response.html.render()
```

[image]

Comment: You'll have to show more code than that. (Please enter code as *text* rather than an image). What is the `r` variable you have there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a bug in the requests-html library that messes up the r.html.render() method in Python 3.8. It gets stuck and won't finish loading the webpage.

To fix it, either use an older version of requests-html (0.10.0 or earlier) or switch to the arender() method instead of render(). The arender() method is a bit trickier but will work in your case!

```
from requests_html import AsyncHTMLSession

async def main():
    async with AsyncHTMLSession() as session:
        r = await session.get('https://example.com')
        await r.html.arender()
        data = r.html.full_text
        print(data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```